# Group by consecutive index numbers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I was wondering if there is a way to groupby consecutive index numbers and move the groups in different columns. Here is an example of the DataFrame I'm using:

```
                 0
0     19218.965703
1     19247.621650
2     19232.651322
9     19279.216956
10    19330.087371
11    19304.316973
```

And my idea is to gruoup by sequential index numbers and get something like this:

```
                 0             1
0     19218.965703  19279.216956    
1     19247.621650  19330.087371
2     19232.651322  19304.316973
```

Ive been trying to split my data by blocks of 3 and then groupby but I was looking more about something that can be used to group and rearrange sequential index numbers.
Thank you!

Comment: #maybe df['v_col'].values.reshape(-1,3).T

Comment: This is a good way to transpose, however I would like to avoid setting the boundaries (-1, 3) in case I have larger more consecutive idx numbers to group. and the @anky_91 reply is the answer to my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
from more_itertools import consecutive_groups
final=pd.concat([df.loc[i].reset_index(drop=True) 
                    for i in consecutive_groups(df.index)],axis=1)
final.columns=range(len(final.columns))
print(final)
```

---

```
              0             1
0  19218.965703  19279.216956
1  19247.621650  19330.087371
2  19232.651322  19304.316973
```

Comment: I like the more_itertools solution! Thank you. With 3 answers you guys covered all the possible and elegant solutions!!

Answer (score 10):

This is a `groupby` + `pivot_table`

---

```
m = df.index.to_series().diff().ne(1).cumsum()

(df.assign(key=df.groupby(m).cumcount())
    .pivot_table(index='key', columns=m, values=0))
```

```
                1             2
key
0    19218.965703  19279.216956
1    19247.621650  19330.087371
2    19232.651322  19304.316973
```

Answer (score 10):

#### Create a new `pandas.Series` with a new `pandas.MultiIndex`

```
a = pd.factorize(df.index - np.arange(len(df)))[0]
b = df.groupby(a).cumcount()

pd.Series(df['0'].to_numpy(), [b, a]).unstack()

              0             1
0  19218.965703  19279.216956
1  19247.621650  19330.087371
2  19232.651322  19304.316973
```

---

#### Similar but with more Numpy

```
a = pd.factorize(df.index - np.arange(len(df)))[0]
b = df.groupby(a).cumcount()

c = np.empty((b.max() + 1, a.max() + 1), float)
c.fill(np.nan)
c[b, a] = np.ravel(df)
pd.DataFrame(c)

              0             1
0  19218.965703  19279.216956
1  19247.621650  19330.087371
2  19232.651322  19304.316973
```

Comment: This solution is *very* clever! The offset relative to `np.arange` should increase after every "gap" in the sequence, so the offset value should uniquely identify runs of consecutive values. Then `pd.factorize` will create unique indicators for those unique offsets.

Answer (score 7):

One way from `pandas` `groupby`

```
s=df.index.to_series().diff().ne(1).cumsum()
pd.concat({x: y.reset_index(drop=True) for x, y in df['0'].groupby(s)}, axis=1)

Out[786]: 
              1             2
0  19218.965703  19279.216956
1  19247.621650  19330.087371
2  19232.651322  19304.316973
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have assumed that the number of observations within each consecutive group will be the same. My approach is:

Prepare the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data ={'data':[19218.965703 ,19247.621650 ,19232.651322 ,19279.216956 ,19330.087371 ,19304.316973]}, index = [0,1,2,9,10,11] )
```

And the solution:

```
df['Group'] = (df.index.to_series()-np.arange(df.shape[0])).rank(method='dense')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['Observations'] = df.groupby(['Group'])['index'].rank()
df.pivot(index='Observations',columns='Group', values='data')
```

Which returns:

```
Group                  1.0           2.0
Observations                            
1.0           19218.965703  19279.216956
2.0           19247.621650  19330.087371
3.0           19232.651322  19304.316973
```

Answer (score 1):

My way:

```
df['groups']=list(df.reset_index()['index']-range(0,len(df)))
pd.concat([df[df['groups']==i][['0']].reset_index(drop=True) for i in df['groups'].unique()],axis=1)

              0             0
0  19218.965703  19279.216956
1  19247.621650  19330.087371
2  19232.651322  19304.316973
```